# How to replace fan fixture for a flat LED light fixture?

Tags: light-fixture

I removed a fan from the ceiling and noticed this pole in the picture below. I'm wondering what to do with this if I want to install a flat back LED light fixture. Should I cut it or is there a cover I can use? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the four drywall screws in the existing bracket and remove it. Then see about removing the pipe, it might just be part of the bracket. If there is an electrical box up there you can mount the led  fixture. If not, you'll have to install one. Was the fan controlled by a wall switch or a pull chain?

Comment: pull chain. There is no switch for this fan.

Comment: @Bun  Then just make sure you led fixture has a switch to operate it.  Good luck.

Comment: You may have to remove the pipe from the attic or cut a hole in the new fixture to pass it through, if there's enough clearance in the new fixture.